# From prototype to real APP

Tags: ios, user-interface, prototype, converters

I am a starter now developing my own IOS APP, but ran into the trouble: I really want to work out some cool UI, and do find lots of tools that will do exactly what I am thinking, however they seems to only give a prototype design.
I am wondering is that possible that we can convert the prototype to excitable objective-c code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use xCode and Interface Builder, no other tool, your prototype is ready to be built and run.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply, but what I mean is that I used tool like sketch and origami, because they can help do exactly what I need. So is there any possibility that I can implement the prototype from origami?

Comment: You must build your app with XCode. So natively, you can't. Check if a XCode plugin exists. If not, you will have to use IB and integrate your images, animation and so forth. Welcome to iOS development ;))